# spring input validation with put request

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, spring-boot, put

good day everyone,

i have this spring rest api that i'm building, and currently having a problem with the put method on my of controllers.

i have a question entity that has a relation with a test entity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name="question_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name="question_text", nullable = false)
@NotNull
private String question;

@Column(name="question_weight", nullable = false)
@Min(1)
private Integer weight = 1;

@Column(name="question_type", nullable = false)
private String type = "radio";

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "last_modified", nullable = false)
@LastModifiedDate
private Date lastModified;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, targetEntity = com.QCMGenerator.QCMGenerator.Model.Test.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "test_id", referencedColumnName = "test_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JsonIgnore
private Test test;
```

i posted earlier asking about this problem and i've been told to use the DTOs, so i did and here is my question DTO:

```
private Long id;

private String question;

private String type;

private Integer weight;

private Date lastModified;

private TestDTO test;
```

and this the put method i have in my controller:

```
@PutMapping("/{questionID}")
public QuestionDTO updateQuestion(
        @PathVariable(value = "testID") Long testID,
        @PathVariable(value = "questionID") Long questionID,
        @Valid @RequestBody QuestionDTO newQuestion
){
    if(!testRepo.existsById(testID)){
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("No test with the ID '"+testID+"' was found...");
    }

    QuestionDTO savedDTO = null;

    try {
        Question questionEntity = questionRepo.findById(questionID).get();
        QuestionDTO questionDTO = convertToDTO(questionEntity);
        if (newQuestion.getTest() != null) {
            questionDTO.setTest(newQuestion.getTest());
        }
        if (newQuestion.getQuestion() != null) {
            questionDTO.setQuestion(newQuestion.getQuestion());
        }
        if (newQuestion.getType() != null) {
            questionDTO.setType(newQuestion.getType());
        }
        if (newQuestion.getWeight() != null) {
            questionDTO.setWeight(newQuestion.getWeight());
        }
        Question newQuestionEntity = convertToEntity(questionDTO);
        Question saved = questionRepo.save(newQuestionEntity);
        savedDTO = convertToDTO(saved);
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return savedDTO;
}
```

and i keep getting this error on my IDE console:

> 2018-11-18 21:33:12.249  WARN 12876 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.a.i.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions    : HHH000437: Attempting to save one or more entities that have a non-nullable association with an unsaved transient entity. The unsaved transient entity must be saved in an operation prior to saving these dependent entities.
>       Unsaved transient entity: ([com.QCMGenerator.QCMGenerator.Model.Test#])
>       Dependent entities: ([[com.QCMGenerator.QCMGenerator.Model.Question#10]])
>       Non-nullable association(s): ([com.QCMGenerator.QCMGenerator.Model.Question.test])
>   org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : com.QCMGenerator.QCMGenerator.Model.Question.test -> com.QCMGenerator.QCMGenerator.Model.Test; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : com.QCMGenerator.QCMGenerator.Model.Question.test -> com.QCMGenerator.QCMGenerator.Model.Test

i was hoping someone here would clarify this problem for me as i have been stuck all day long just on that single method or the other methods work fine, i have tried with and without a DTO and before adding it i was having a problem with the method accepting null values on certain fields.

i really appreciate any help given and thank you all for your help.

have a good day everyone. :D

Comment: try to debug the put request in eclipse and check the values

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you are trying to save an entity association with null id.
Means is this case `convertToEntity` method in 
`Question newQuestionEntity = convertToEntity(questionDTO);`

returns questionEntity with new `Test` object.
you should check all relations inside an entity for being null when their id is null.

Comment: i'm sorry but i didn't understand how exactly i can solve this problem, can you please elaborate more ?

Answer (score 0):

You need add ID in your entity in order to save an entity with that ID as reference.

Easy to solve it:

```
Question newQuestionEntity = convertToEntity(questionDTO);
newQuestionEntity.setId(testID);
```

A best solution would be:

```
questionDTO.setID(testID);
public Question convertToEntity(QuestionDTO qDto) {
       Question question = new Question(qDto.getID()) ;
        ....... 
        return question;
}
```

Comment: i didn't understand where the problem exactly ? is it the question entity or the test entity and which one i need to set the id of ?

Comment: Your issue is that you aren't adding the entity ID before you save, when you update an element you need to add entity ID which will be updated.

Comment: which id do i need to set ? the test id or the question id ? cuz i did try to set both and it didn't work

Comment: never mind the problem is i didn't check for null fields

Comment: if its about the error it is already solved otherwise just send me a pm an i'll give you the code i have so far